# How can I always see ethereal and incorporeal creatures?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, character-creation, undead, spirits

I am trying to adapt a character who can see spirits continuously to Pathfinder.

I looked all over the d20pfsrd site for a feat or supernatural ability that lets a character continuously see ethereal or incorporeal beings as if seeing normally rather than having to cast a spell.  The closest things I can find are the Ghost Sight trait from Wayfinder, but it seems pretty vague and more like just knowing a ghost or spirit is still there; and the medium's Spirit Sense (from Purple Duck Games) and the Aetherurgist oracle archetype (from Rite Publishing), but these seem to need to be cast rather than being an innate sense like Darkvision.

I don't know if anyone has tried this before but basically think of characters that don't really choose to find ghosts, they just see them when they are there (like in the movies *The Sixth Sense* and *ParaNorman*). I don't know if it counts as overpowered either.

Answer (score 2):

There is a 2nd Level Wizard spell called "See Invisible" which can be made Permanent through the Permanency Spell. To get this done at the earliest levels, you'd have to purchase two scrolls:

> A CL 10 Permanency Scroll: 1,250 gp
>   A See Invisibility Scroll: 150 gp
>   Diamond Dust Material Components: 5,000 gp
>   **Total: 6,400 gp**

You also need to be able to cast the scrolls (DC 30 UMD check for non-wizards).

However that's really expensive. It can also be made as a wondrous item at your GM's discretion  as a constant effect for 12,000 gp (6,000 gp if crafted by a fellow player who has the Craft Wondrous Item feat).

Unfortunately, that's even more expensive (and still just as expensive if someone crafts it at half-cost).

Comment: So basically, "It would be easier to just ask your GM to homebrew the feature"?

Comment: Easier for the player to obtain, almost certainly. The permanency rules are fine (in this instance...), IMO, though permanency also has a material component based on the spell which adds 5000GP to the cost of the scroll solution.

Comment: I don't see 6000gp as too expensive. Permanent See Invisible is extremely useful.

Comment: I think in case of two scrolls that's 6400gp per 'dispel magic' cast on you by a caster 'of higher level than you were when you cast the spell'. So the wondrous item solution is way cheaper even for a full price.

Comment: For a level 1-6 it is too expensive. Pathfinder states that you shouldn't have a magic item that's worth more than half your total wealth. As for the permanency, that's the cheapest you can find that effect and yes it is costly if dispelled.